# Yammer REST API > Authentication without user input

Tags: api, rest, yammer

My project has a requirement to automatically post messages to a user in Yammer when an event occurs.  I've looked at the Yammer authentication documentation at...

https://developer.yammer.com/authentication/

... and the examples shown for server-side flow involve a client-side login via Yammer's OAuth dialog.  I need for authentication to occur via a server-side platform (PHP in this case, but I can use anything) with no user interaction.

Can anyone suggest an approach or is a client-side interaction required by design?

Thanks!!!

Eric

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A friend helped me out with this one.  Most social network APIs use OAuth three-legged authentication which allows a user to give authorization to a service without presenting (or making another) login.  This is by design.  Circumventing the authentication portion may be possible, but ethical questions come into play.